# Bash command not working inside loop

Tags: linux, bash

i have this piece of code

```
for f in ${CURRENT_IMAGE_FILES[@]}; 
do 
    echo "Checking if too many process are running"
    while :
    do
        RUNNING_PROCESS=`ps aux | grep [f]fmpeg -c`
        if [[ $RUNNING_PROCESS -gt 22 ]]
        then
            echo "Too many process running now, sleep for 1 second"
            sleep 1
        else
            echo "Total ffmpeg process running is less then 20, continue"
            echo "current process count is " $RUNNING_PROCESS
            break
        fi
    done
    convert $f -resize 1280x720 -gravity center $f
    composite -gravity center $f /var/bash/b.jpg $f
    ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i $f -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -preset ultrafast -t 3 $DIR/$COUNT.mp4 &
    ((++COUNT))
done
```

The thing is that when place inside the for loop, grep command is getting an error. Something along the lines of Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.

But when place outside the for loop, i do not get such error. Is there something wrong with my loop that is interfering with grep?

Comment: Not sure why the code behaves any differently inside a loop but you should check out http://www.shellcheck.net/ as there are a lot of things that you can tidy up in your script.

Comment: Just `grep fmpeg` - it will find `ffmpeg` too

Comment: Consider putting all your `$f` inside double quotes so you can process files with spaces in their names, thus `"$f"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you are using `[ and`]`as`grep` pattern but pattern is **unquoted**. Try this in BASH:

```
RUNNING_PROCESS=$(ps aux | grep '[f]fmpeg' -c)
```

Alternatively if you have `pgrep` then you can use:

```
RUNNING_PROCESS=$(pgrep -f 'ffmpeg' | wc -l)
```

Comment: This would both also count other processes that have `ffmpeg` in a command argument, like `vim notes-on-ffmpeg-commands.txt`.

Comment: Yes of course that will be found in `grep`. Intent of answer was to fix the error OP was getting in `grep` command. Is that the reason for you to downvote?

Comment: It is, an I see no other potential reason. I see your point that it is not part of the question to fix that; But still, the command in the answer implies that it gets the count of running `ffmpeg` processes, while it does not.

Comment: No where I wrote in my answer that answer is trying to avoid `vim abc-ffmpeg.txt` processes. Let's not mix the 2 different issues here.

Comment: Ok, you almost convinced me ;) Oh, looks like I can not "unvote" until an edit.

Answer (score 1):

You are using grep with the `options` in the wrong order and the `[f]` character class is unnecessary. From **man grep**

```
grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]
```

So you should change your `RUNNING_PROCESS` command to

```
RUNNING_PROCESS=`ps aux | grep -c ffmpeg`
```

Additionally, why are you using `[f]fmpeg`? The **character class** `[f]` will only match/expand to `f`, so get rid of it to prevent grep from interpreting it as part of the pattern. Further, it does not help as a wildcard as `fmpeg` will match anything `ffmpeg` will match.

Comment: This gives a wrong count, because the `grep` will match itself in the `ps` output.

Comment: He uses [f]fmpeg to avoid grep finding himself on the ps aux list.

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
RUNNING_PROCESS=`ps aux | grep [f]fmpeg -c`
```

to count the process instances of `ffmpeg` currently running.

The `[f]` is used so that `grep [f]fmpeg` does not match it's own command line, that's good.

But there's a problem: The `[f]` is unquoted, so the shell may try to interpret it, depending on options.

Quoting it should make the line work:

```
RUNNING_PROCESS=`ps aux | grep '[f]fmpeg' -c`
```

There is another problem in this: it matches not only `ffmpeg -a foo -b bar ...`, but also `less ffmpeg-manual.txt` or `vim notes-on-ffmpeg-commands.txt`.

But there is a better way to do that - using the right tool for the job.
`ps` is the right to list processes, but for matching processes, `pgrep` is better suited:

```
RUNNING_PROCESS=$(pgrep -c ffmpeg)
```

does the what you need, getting the count of processes of `ffmpeg` into `RUNNING_PROCESS`.

The above works for `pgrep` of the package `procps`, common in Linux. There are versions that do not support `-c` for count, or use `-c` for something else. If it does not work, use:

```
RUNNING_PROCESS=$(pgrep ffmpeg | wc -l)
```

`pgrep` takes care of not matching itself on its own, so there is no need for the `[f]` workaround.
I also replaced the back quotes ` ... ` by `$( ... )`, which has some advantages if you need to nest it.

If you do need to match not only command name, but command line too, use `pgrep -f`.

Comment: i'm getting pgrep: invalid option -- 'c'
Usage: pgrep [-flvx] [-d DELIM] [-n|-o] [-P PPIDLIST] [-g PGRPLIST] [-s SIDLIST]
 [-u EUIDLIST] [-U UIDLIST] [-G GIDLIST] [-t TERMLIST] [PATTERN]

Comment: Oh... I'm on Ubuntu 14.4, `pgrep --version` says `pgrep from procps-ng 3.3.9`. Are you on some BSD variant?

Comment: Yea , i am using Amazon own linux flavor

Comment: @user3148070 Ok, added the alternative. There is also a `pgrep` under Solaris that has `-c`, but for something else.